# Trouble with next/previous buttons with IQKeyboardManager

Tags: ios, swift, iqkeyboardmanager

I am working in a Swift project where I have several input fields. I made a custom view for each of the input fields because we use them a lot in the project.

I added `IQKeyboardManager` to the project. It works really good, and the view gets up according to the active text field.

However, the Next/Previous buttons do not appear. I have tried setting the tags of the text fields in code like this:

```
slNameField.setTextField("Name", keyboardType: UIKeyboardType.NamePhonePad, image: UIImage(named: "ic_name"))
slNameField.txtField.tag = 101

slEmailField.setTextField("Email", keyboardType: UIKeyboardType.EmailAddress, image: UIImage(named: "ic_email"))
slEmailField.txtField.tag = 102

slLocationField.setTextField("City, Country", keyboardType: nil, image: UIImage(named: "ic_location"))
slLocationField.txtField.tag = 103
```

Here's some illustrations of the project:

[image: The Signup Screen]

Answer (score 27):

I am also stuck into same problem. As mentioned by @sam there is a very helpful demo project of the library.

**Solution** 
You only need to select the UIView in which all the textField or UIViews are. And then you just need to change it's class to

> **"IQPreviousNextView"**

And all of the rest will be handled by the library.

**Problem screen image**

[image]

**And solution is screen short**

[image]

Hope it help :). it saved my day.

Comment: Very help full indeed.

Comment: Exactly needed :)

Comment: You saved another day in the world ;)

Answer (score 7):

@Ibrahim Yildirim, If next and previous buttons are not appearing on toolbar this is because textfields must not be in same uiview. they will only appear if all textfields are in same super view .

Comment: From now you can use '-(void)considerToolbarPreviousNextInViewClass:(Class)toolbarPreviousNextConsideredClass' method to work it with other sublings too. I'll add a demo functionality in repo code.

Comment: Download Demo Project from https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager...

& CustomView has the same solution you want

Answer (score 2):

Please add the line of code in your app delegate file (AppDelegate.swift) in this function: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. 
The line of code: IQKeyboardManager.shared.previousNextDisplayMode = .alwaysShow

Comment: The best solution is to give class "IQPreviousNextView" to that main view, using your solution will show next previous arrow even if  there is only one textField in view.

Answer (score 1):

go to the IQUIView+IQKeyboardToolbar.m file and do the following changes

### Just change the following method stuff

```
- (void)addPreviousNextDoneOnKeyboardWithTarget:(id)target previousAction:(SEL)previousAction nextAction:(SEL)nextAction doneAction:(SEL)doneAction titleText:(NSString*)titleText
- (void)addPreviousNextRightOnKeyboardWithTarget:(id)target rightButtonImage:(UIImage*)rightButtonImage previousAction:(SEL)previousAction nextAction:(SEL)nextAction rightButtonAction:(SEL)rightButtonAction titleText:(NSString*)titleText
- (void)addPreviousNextRightOnKeyboardWithTarget:(id)target rightButtonTitle:(NSString*)rightButtonTitle previousAction:(SEL)previousAction nextAction:(SEL)nextAction rightButtonAction:(SEL)rightButtonAction titleText:(NSString*)titleText
```

#### find the for next button code in above listed method

//Next button

```
IQBarButtonItem *next = [[IQBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:imageRightArrow style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:target action:nextAction];
```

//replaces with this code

```
 IQBarButtonItem *next = [[IQBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Next" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:target action:nextAction];
```

#### find the for Previous button code in above listed method

//Previous button

```
IQBarButtonItem *prev = [[IQBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:imageLeftArrow style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:target action:previousAction];
```

//replaces with this code

```
 IQBarButtonItem *prev = [[IQBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Previous" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:target action:previousAction];
```

Comment: This question is tagged "swift", not "objective-c".

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put this whole hierarchy inside the IQPreviousNextView.

Assign IQPreviousNextView class to UIView (parent view) from storyboard. It will start working.

[image]

[image]